# How to verify pressed key on OnKeyUp event

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I have a lot of lines to check the typed content of a edit1.text field, but I need to use the OnKeyUp event (for some reasons), so how can I 'translate' this code to Key:Word type (normaly its Key:Char on OnKeyPress)?

```
if not (key in ['0'..'9', #08]) then begin
  key:=#0;
```

Comment: This looks all wrong it's when the key goes down that decisiona need to be taken. Just try typing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ord( Key ) to convert a keyboard Key's Word value to a character value. Otherwise use a VK_ value if available.

In your snippet you've mixed char's ( '0'..'9' ) with Values ( #08 ), I'm not sure that is ok you need to test it. If not then ( #08 ) needs to be checked either directly to Key or Chr( Key ) in another comparison.

Also it may be preferable to use VK_UNKNOWN rather than #0.

Here is a KeyUp event I'm using in some working code I've written in Lazarus. HTH.

```
    procedure TfrmMain.lbCmdLinesKeyUp( Sender : TObject; var Key : Word; Shift : TShiftState );
begin

  if ( Key = vk_return ) and ( lbCmdLines.ItemIndex > -1 ) then
  begin
    if ( Shift = [ ssCtrl ] ) then
    begin
      if btnLineEdit.Enabled then
        btnLineEdit.Click;
    end
    else
    begin
      if btnRun.Enabled then
        btnRun.Click;
    end;
  end;

  if ( Key = Ord( 'C' ) ) or ( Key = Ord( 'c' ) ) then
  begin
    if Shift = [ ssCtrl ] then
        actCopyClipCmdLine.Execute;
//order, apparently, doesn't matter, both work
    //if Shift = [ ssCtrl, ssShift ] then
    if Shift = [ ssShift, ssCtrl ] then
      mniCopyCLListClipClick( Self );
    //if ( ssCtrl in Shift ) and ( ssShift in Shift ) and ( ssAlt in Shift ) then
    if Shift = [ ssCtrl, ssShift, ssAlt ] then
      actCopyCmdLine.Execute;
  end;
end;
```